# Will there be any conflit with error object thrown from mongoose.save() on try-catch blocks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider following codes:

```
mongoose.connect('MyDatabaseURL');
var sch_obj = {field1: String};
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    var model_obj = db.model('SchemaName', sch_obj);
    var obj = new model_obj({field1:'MyValue'});
    obj.save(function(err,data){
      if(err) 
         console.log('error occurred:' + err);   // <=== Case 1
      else
         console.log('saved'); 
      });
});

/* ----------------------------------  */

mongoose.connect('MyDatabaseURL');
var sch_obj = {field1: String};
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    var model_obj = db.model('SchemaName', sch_obj);
    var obj = new model_obj({field1:'MyValue'});
    obj.save(function(err,data){
      try {
          console.log('saved');
      }
      catch(err)                            // <=== Case 2
      {
        console.log('error occurred:' + err);
      }
    });
});
```

**Question**: Are they same? If yes which one is the good way to handle error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not the same. Mongoose newer throws errors, so you'll newer catch one. It's why you can't use `try ... catch ...` statement to handle mongoose errors.

So, the only right way is:

```
obj.save(function(err,data){
  if(err)
     console.log('error occurred:' + err);
  else
     // err == null
     console.log('saved'); 
  });
```

The reason behind it is that `throw` terminates the current process unless it caught. So, most nodejs modules (e.g. `express`, `mongoose`, etc.) passes their errors using callback instead of throwing them, its a common practice in nodejs.

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni, see [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) for more examples of proper error handling.